# Issue with fork and wait system call

Tags: c++, fork, pipe, wait

I have written a basic c++ program in unix with fork() and wait() system call. I am only creating one child. I have used two pipes. So After fork operation with first pipe i am writing from child to parent and as after parent receives the data, parent is writing back to child in second pipe. after that in parent side I am using wait(0) system call. but still my parent process dies before child process?

structure is something like this:

```
 main()
 char buff[] = "Parent process kills";
 char cuff[] = "before Child process";
 int fd1[2];
 int fd2[2];
 pipe(fd1);
 pipe(fd2);
 if((pid = fork()) == 0)
 {
   close(fd1[0]);
   close(fd2[1]);
   write(fd1[1],buff,strlen(buff)+1);
   read(fd2[0],cuff,sizeof(cuff));

 }
 else
 {
    close(fd1[1]);
    close(fd2[0]);

    read(fd1[0],buff,sizeof(buff));
    write(fd2[1],cuff,strlen(cuff)+1);
    wait((int *) 0);
  }

  close(fd1);
  close(fd2);

  }'
```

Even though wait() is used but still parent process dies before child. 
Thanks in adavance.

Comment: Remember that `fork` can fail, and in that case returns `-1`. So your `if` statement will not work in that case. You should *always* check return values for failures.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `read` result in undefined behavior. You try to read into string literals, not the buffers you have. In this case it probably results in a crash.

Your `write` calls also writes a string literal and not the buffer you have.

Also, since you have character arrays initialized to strings, `sizeo(buff)` and `strlen(buff) + 1` are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're not dying due to a segfault?  Each of these commands is trying to send more than you intend:

```
write(fd1[1],"buff",strlen(buff)+1);
```

and

```
write(fd2[1],"cuff",strlen(cuff)+1);
```

and each of these is trying to receive into read-only memory:

```
read(fd2[0],"cuff",sizeof(cuff));
```

and

```
read(fd1[0],"buff",sizeof(buff));
```

Comment: In accutal code is This is the accutal code. Kindly look into this code explain why parent process exits before child process.

 main()
 pid_t pid;
 char buff[] = "Parent process kills";
 char cuff[] = "before Child process";
 int fd1[2];
 int fd2[2];
 pipe(fd1);
 pipe(fd2);
 if((pid = fork()) = 0)
 {
   close(fd1[0]);
   close(fd2[1]);
   write(fd1[1],buff,strlen(buff)+1);
   read(fd2[0],cuff,sizeof(cuff));

 }
 else
 {
    close(fd1[1]);
    close(fd2[0]);

    read(fd1[0],buff,sizeof(buff));
    write(fd2[1],cuff,strlen(cuff)+1);
    wait((int *) 0);
  }

  close(fd1);
  close(fd2);

  }

Answer (score 0):

There is a subtle error in the line

```
if(pid == fork())
```

You compare the result of fork() with pid instead of assigning to it and comparing it to zero. What you wanted to write is this:

```
if((pid = fork()))
```

Note the extra set of parentheses that tells the compiler that you really want to do the assignment, and that you don't want get a warning on it.

And with the corrected if, you have the parent executing the first case, not the second, so the correct code would be:

```
if(pid == fork()) {
  close(fd1[1]);
  close(fd2[0]);

  read(fd1[0],"buff",sizeof(buff));
  write(fd2[1],"cuff",strlen(cuff)+1);
  wait((int *) 0);
} else {
  close(fd1[0]);
  close(fd2[1]);
  write(fd1[1],"buff",strlen(buff)+1);
  read(fd2[0],"cuff",sizeof(cuff));
}
```

Comment: This is the accutal code.  Kindly look into this code explain why parent process exits before child process.

 main()
 pid_t pid;
 char buff[] = "Parent process kills";
 char cuff[] = "before Child process";
 int fd1[2];
 int fd2[2];
 pipe(fd1);
 pipe(fd2);
 if((pid = fork()) = 0)
 {
   close(fd1[0]);
   close(fd2[1]);
   write(fd1[1],buff,strlen(buff)+1);
   read(fd2[0],cuff,sizeof(cuff));

 }
 else
 {
    close(fd1[1]);
    close(fd2[0]);

    read(fd1[0],buff,sizeof(buff));
    write(fd2[1],cuff,strlen(cuff)+1);
    wait((int *) 0);
  }

  close(fd1);
  close(fd2);

  }

Comment: Remember that a single equal sign is _always_ an assignment. So `if((pid = fork()) = 0)` first assigns the return value to pid, and the assigns zero to it, which is also the value of the entire expression. And zero is false. So both processes, child and parent, execute the `else` clause. Consequently, both processes close the same end of the pipe => when they read from it, there is no writing end open anymore. Please look at the man page of pipe, and you will find a complete working example.